# Noticeable stutter on a webkit keyframe animation

Tags: css, css-animations

I'm using a keyframe animation to move a large image (1500px) left to right within a containing div very slowly over 3 mins on an infinite loop. I have easing and an empty translate 3D properity turned on however I'm still getting a stutter when the image approaches the 50% keyframe and 100% keyframe. Are there any other solutions to create a smooth easing?

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery UI? But you shouldn't be having stuttering with css animation...

Comment: I haven't tried using jquery yet but that would be the next thing I would try. I'd like to just use CSS if I can as this is for tablet devices

Comment: The stutter occurs on the tablet? Or on a desktop PC?